# jQuery slideToggle div using 1 button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me on my problem using jQuery slideToggle. I want to slideToggle div using 1 button but it seems not working

here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnaddphone").click(function () {
        $("#togbap").hide();
        $("#togbap").slideToggle();
    });
</script>

<div id="AddPhone">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="300" height="150" style="text-align:left">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnaddphone" runat="server" Text="+" OnClientClick="return false;" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lbbus10" runat="server" Text="Add Phone"></asp:Label>
                    <div id="togbap">
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="aplandline" runat="server" Text="Landline work"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="aptxt1" class="basetxt" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="aphppersonal" runat="server" Text="Handphone personal" ></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="aptxt2" class="basetxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="aphpwork" runat="server" Text="Handphone work"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="aptxt3" class="basetxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div></td>
                    <td width="300"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
```

it's inside the dialog box btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all place your code inside document ready. Secondly,place the hide code before the click event or you will have the same action on the click event taking out the purpose of using `slideToggle`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#togbap").hide();
    $("#btnaddphone").click(function () {
        $("#togbap").slideToggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```